# var with quotes inside var with quotes

Tags: bash, curl

I want to set my user agent from a string I've got in a variable, however there are some other options as well that I want to pass in the same string, so this is what I ended up with:

```
cookie="-b cookie -c cookie"
agent="My Bot"
opt="-A \"$agent\" $cookie"

curl http://example.com $opt
```

When I run my script it fetches the site but it doesn't set the whole user agent but just the part before the first space and then goes

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bot
```

I'm guessing there is something messing up with the quotes, but if I replace `curl` with echo this is what I see, which seems pretty accurate to me

```
http://example.com -A "My Bot" -b cookie -c cookie
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has a detailed discussion of this issue and several approaches to fixing it (the most appropriate for your use case probably being the one in John Kugelman's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle whitespace correctly store arguments in arrays, not strings.

```
cookie=(-b cookie -c cookie)
agent="My Bot"
opt=(-A "$agent" "${cookie[@]}")

curl http://example.com "${opt[@]}"
```

> I'm guessing there is something messing up with the quotes, but if I replace curl with echo this is what I see, which seems pretty accurate to me.

`echo` is misleading. If you want to be absolutely sure, use `set -x`.

```
$ set -x
$ curl http://example.com $opt
+ curl http://example.com -A '"My' 'Bot"' -b cookie -c cookie
```

See how it turned `"My Bot"` into two arguments, `'"My'` and `'Bot"'`?

Comment: yes I see, but how do I prevent that? I just did what you've shown with the arrays and the result is still the same.

Comment: I just found out that my problem was that i was doing `o="${opt[@]}"` and then `curl $o`. Is it possible to assign the output of `${opt[@]}` to a variable instead of having to type it out everywhere?

Comment: No, you have to type it out. Assigning to a variable without parentheses flattens the string and removes the array-ness of it.

Comment: Cool. In this case I just made a function `fetch() { curl $* "${opt[@]}" }` then call with any parameters `fetch http://example.com -d mydata` - for anyone who might be reading this in the future.

Comment: Make that `curl "$@" "${opt[@]}"`.

Comment: @php_nub_q, ...in addition to John's note above (about using `"$@"` instead of `$*`), I'd also strongly suggest putting the options *first*, before the positional arguments. Let's say the user passes in `--` as an argument -- that string means "end of options", so it would stop the options from your array from being honored. See also Guidelines 9 and 10 at the end of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html